# Loop through folders and count files in TARs

Tags: bash, command-line, find, tar, wc

I need to go through folders and count files in TARs with same  name.

I tried this:

```
find -name example.tar -exec tar -tf {} + | wc -l
```

But it fails:

```
tar: ./rajce/rajce/example.tar: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
0
```

It works when there is only one example.tar.

I need separate number for each file.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly means "it fails". Please [edit] your question and show the exact error message or describe what happens and what you would want to happen. Please don't show "something like" what you tried, show the real code.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/578735/edit) your question to specify _in what way_ it fails? Ideally, post the console output that results when you run your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `tar -tf {} \;` instead of `tar -tf {} +` to run `tar` with
each tarball individually.  In GNU `man find` it says:

```
   -exec command {} +

          This variant of the -exec action runs the specified
          command on the selected files, but the command line is
          built by appending each selected file name at the end;
          the total number of invocations of the command will be
          much less than the number of matched files.  The command
          line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its
          command lines.  Only one instance of `{}' is allowed
          within the com- mand.  The command is executed in the
          starting directory.
```

Your command is equivalent to `tar tf example.tar example.tar`.
You're also missing `[path...]` argument - some implementations of
`find`, for example BSD find will return `find: illegal option -- n`
error. All in all it should be:

```
find . -name example.tar -exec tar -tf {} \; | wc -l
```

And notice that in that case `wc -l` will count number of files in all
`example.tar` files found.  You can use `-maxdepth 1` to search for
`example.tar` files only in the current directory. If you want to search for all `example.tar` recursively and print results for each one individually (notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the command):

```
$ find . -name example.tar -exec sh -c 'tar -tf "$1" | wc -l' sh {} \;
3
3
```

and with directory names prepended:

```
$ find . -name example.tar -exec sh -c 'printf "%s: " "$1" && tar -tf "$1" | wc -l' sh {} \;
./example.tar: 3
./other/example.tar: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the use of the `+` operator for the `-exec` operation of `find`. The `+` operator means "Concatenate the results of `find` to a space-separated list and execute the specified command with that list as argument".

That means that if there is more than one file `example.tar` (say, two) under different paths, your `-exec` command will look like

```
tar -tf /path/1/to/example.tar /path/2/to/example.tar
```

etc. That, however will be interpreted as "look if there is a file */path/2/to/example.tar* in the TAR-file */path/1/to/example.tar*", which should obviously not be the case.

You should be fine if you modify your code as

```
find -name example.tar -exec tar -tf {} \; | wc -l
```

which will execute the `tar` command separately for each file found.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to print result separate for every file? This code prints sum of all files.

Comment: I see @ArkadiuszDrabczyk has already included the solution in his answer, so I will simply refer you to that.